# Test Class is not working for contacts

Tags: apex, unit-test

I wrote a test class for below webservice but it **showing an contacts does not exist in test class may i know what is the problem, how to declare that contacts in test class

```
   global class MainClass89
{
     global class RequestClass
     {


  // RESPONSE CLASS 


   return res;
}
```

}

And My test class is

```
@isTest
private class Test12 {
    public  static testMethod void UnitTest() {
     //   MainClass89 mainInput = new MainClass89();

     accWrapper.accName = 'Stest';
    accWrapper.accNumber = '12389';
    //Then add the accWrapper to the list
    req.accounts.add(accWrapper);
    //Now call your method with the proper RequestClass parameter
    MainClass89.behaviourOfWebService(req);
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Sathya. I edited your post to properly format the code. In the future, when you post questions, please try to properly format the code. You can either use the {} symbol in the editor or provide 4 spaces before a line for it to become a code block. Check out the Tour to figure out more of the site's features - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour. Improper formatting typically leads to no one answering your question.

Comment: @Sathya How did your test class saved? In last line of your code you are passing instance of `MainClass89 ` in a method which accepts argument type of `RequestClass `.

Comment: @ regal My test class is doesn't save. it shows an error which i was mention above. can you suggest me.

Comment: You're trying to assign the string property of your wrapper class to an account object. That is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is there is no such variable mainInput.accounts. Looks like you'll need to instantiate your inner requestClass and then the MainClass89.AccountWrapper List within it, like so:

```
@isTest
private class Test12 {
    public  static testMethod void UnitTest() {
        MainClass89 mainInput = new MainClass89();
        MainClass89.AccountWrapper accWrapper = new MainClass89.AccountWrapper();
        accWrapper.accName = 'Test Account';
        accWrapper.accNumber = '123';
        //The below is invlaid
        //mainInput.accounts.add(accWrapper);

        //Instead, instantiate RequestClass inner class
        MainClass89.RequestClass req = new MainClass89.RequestClass();
        //Then the accounts list within it (although this could be done in a constructor in your inner class instead)
        req.accounts = new List<MainClass89.AccountWrapper>();
        //Then add the accWrapper to the list
        req.accounts.add(accWrapper);
        //Now call your method with the proper RequestClass parameter
        MainClass89.behaviourOfWebService(req);
    }
}
```

Comment: i used your test class but sample data is not inserting into my account object may i know what is the reason, but it showing code coverage is 92%.

Comment: I used your test class it is saved may i know why sample data is not inserting into objects by using that class and 2 more lines are not cover in that test class i mention comment in my code may i know what i have to do..

Comment: The reason you don't see data is that any DML operation in a test class (any class with the @isTest annotation) is automatically rolled back after the test executes. This prevents you from having to clean up test data from your objects every time unit tests are run.

Comment: Above Webservice i add Contact releated fields may i know how can i add that fields in my test class..

Comment: You've veered off topic from your original question. I believe my original answer helped you but now it is no longer related to your continuously evolving question.

Comment: May i know what i have to do for contacts in test class for my test class it showing contacts are not exist